# Magento2 Use Prefence and Plugin both in single di.xml

Tags: magento2, plugin

For override two files in magento2 one using with prefence and other using plugin ,can we do this in single di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="Vendor\module\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />

     <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="default_config_provider" type="Vendor\module\Model\DefaultConfigProvider"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

I was using this but its not working.Please help me.

Comment: Can you describe why you need it?

Comment: I want to add attribute in minicart thats why I need both file override.Currently I am doing this changing in both core files and working fine but in custom module Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider  is not working